# Taking elements two by two from lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have lists like:

```
['a', '2', 'b', '1', 'c', '4']
['d', '5', 'e', '7', 'f', '4', 'g', '6']
```

And I want to make a dictionary consist of keys as letters and values as numbers. I mean:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 4, 'd':5, 'e':7, 'f':4, 'g':6}
```

Comment: Dictonaries are not ordered by default, so you cant really do that, unless you want to make an OrderedDict

Comment: Also what is your question? What have you tried yourself? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Do you mean to treat the list as a sequence of interleaved keys and values? I.e., the first list should produce the result `{'a': 2,  'b': 1, 'c': 4}` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
>>> l = ['a', '2', 'b', '1', 'c', '4']
>>> it = iter(l)
>>> dict(zip(it, it))
{'a': '2', 'c': '4', 'b': '1'}
```

First you create an iterator out of the list. Then with zip of the iterator with itself you take pair of values from the list. Finally, with `dict` you transform these tuples to your wanted dictionary.

If you also want to do the string to number conversion, then use:

```
{x: int(y) for x, y in zip(it, it)}
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to use `zip` then:

```
{x: int(next(it)) for x in it}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I like this better than the slicing I was playing around with.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the idea but I can only use slicing and range stuff, not those built-in functions.

Comment: @kristofagotaa Why can't you use built-ins? A solution without any built-ins is going to be uglier (possibly a lot uglier, depending on whether the requirement is absolute and whether you want to convert the values into numbers).

Comment: This has some good information, but the attempt at answering the question with its edited requirement of no built-ins uses three built-ins (`iter()`, `next()`, and `int()`, although that last one could be omitted).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The problem states not to use zip after the second or third edit. By the way great answer from you. I upvoted it even though I would prefer you to resist the temptation.

Answer (score 4):

```
l = ['a', '2', 'b', '1', 'c', '4']
d = {k:v for k,v in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])}
```

Or if you want the numbers to be actual numbers:

```
l = ['a', '2', 'b', '1', 'c', '4']
d = {k:int(v) for k,v in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])}
```

Use `float(v)` instead of `int(v)` if the numbers have the potential to be floating-point values instead of whole numbers.

Without using any [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html):

```
l = ['a', '2', 'b', '1', 'c', '4']
d = {}
l1 = l[::2]
l2 = l[1::2]
idx = 0
while 1:
    try:
        d[l1[idx]] = l2[idx]
        idx += 1
    except IndexError:
        break
```

Comment: Has the disadvantage to the iterator approach that it makes copies of the two halves of the list: `l[::2], l[1::2]`

Comment: @smci - True, but with the edit to the question that forbids built-in functions, it may be necessary.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 so you solved his homework. Does it worth it?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor - I don't know how to respond constructively to that.

Comment: Oh, crap, more homework. Then the question was kinda artificial.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the lists into two, one containing the letters and the other containing the keys, with

```
key_list = old_list[::2]
value_list = old_list[1::2]
```

Then you can loop over the two lists at once with `zip` and you can make the dictionary.

Comment: As Tigerhawk has said more elegantly and more quickly.